# How to get value from JSON in Android

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse

I have JSON response:

```
 {"error":100,"result":"{\"distance\":2.4,\"duration\":5,\"price\":0}"}
```

From this response I want to get a "distance" value for example. How to do it?

I tried to do like this:

```
 String distance = String.valueOf(finalResponseDataJOSNObject.getDouble("distance"));
```

but string value is null. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Finally we discovered that it was back-end issue and we fixed it. No additional operations like JSONObject conversation to String, special character removal, etc. was necessary.

Simply:

```
String distance =  
String.valueOf(finalResponseDataJOSNObject.getJSONObject("result").getDouble("di‌​stance"));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: have you Seached on Google..??

Comment: just try to search on google you can find first link

Answer (score 1):

The distance is in a `JSONObject` under result only. So you have to `getJSONObject("result").getDouble("distance")`.

Comment: I tried like this: String distance = String.valueOf(finalResponseDataJOSNObject.getJSONObject("result").getDouble("distance")); my string still is null.

Comment: Then your finalResponseDataJOSNObject is not as you described. What do  you get when printing finalResponseDataJOSNObject.getJSONObject("result")? or just finalResponseDataJOSNObject

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
String json = "{\"error\":100,\"result\":{\"distance\":2.4,\"duration\":5,\"price\":0}}";
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    double distance = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result").getDouble(
            "distance");
    Log.i("DISTANCE", String.valueOf(distance));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in following way:
Remove special character from json string and convert back to json object and process it accordingly:

```
String json = "{\"error\":100,\"result\":{\"distance\":2.4,\"duration\":5,\"price\":0}}";
try{

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json.replaceAll("\"", ""));

    JSONObject jsonObject2=jsonObject.getJSONObject("result");

    String distance=jsonObject2.getString("distance");

    double convertedDistance=Double.valueOf(distance);

    Log.i("DistanceInformation", "My Distance from json is="+distance);



}catch(JSONException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you all who responded.

Finally we discovered that it was back-end issue and we fixed it. No additional operations like JSONObject conversation to String, special character removal, etc. was necessary.

Simply:

```
String distance =  
String.valueOf(finalResponseDataJOSNObject.getJSONObject("result").getDouble("di‌​stance"));
```